# Problems with a Sum in Crystal Reports 2008

Tags: sql, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008

my legacy stored procedure is bringing in the data like this:

```
Person ID | Location ID | Awesome Count (by Location ID)
1         | A           | 2
2         | A           | 2
3         | A           | 2
4         | B           | 3
5         | B           | 3
6         | B           | 3
```

So, since Awesome count is by Location ID, its repeated for each person in that location (A's actual awesome count is 2 (of the 3 people) and B's is 3 of 3.  The problem occurs when I try to Sum the Awesome count for all locations.  In this example, `Sum(Awesome Count, Location ID)` yields 15 instead of 5 because it sums for all person IDs.  Is there something like a Distinct Sum?

I also tried a 2 step formula, where first formula was `Maximum(Awesome Count, Location ID)` and second formula was `Sum(1st formula)`, but the second formula says "This field cannot be summarized when I hit save.

Any thoughts would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up creating 2 running totals for `Awesome Count`, one that reset every change in the `Location ID` group (total per location), and one that did not reset (grand total).

Answer (score 1):

1. First option would be check `Select Distinct Records` option in `Database`.
2. Try below. This solution works assuming `Awesome Count is always same for Location ID`

a. Create a group with `Location ID`

b. Place the `Awesome Count` in detail section

c. Now create a formula `@Result` in group footer of the `Location ID`

```
Sum(Awesome Count, Location ID)/count(Awesome Count, Location ID)
```

Comment: Thanks! While I'm sure this would work I actually had a moment of inspiration and figured it out using the Running Totals and have one reset on change of Location ID (count for each location) and one not resetting at all (total count).